# Separate Data Calls using factory in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-factory

I am using Angular's `$http` for `get`, `post`, `put` and `delete` operations. Right now i have written this code in my Angular controller.

**-- Now --**

I want to use `$resource` instead of `$http` and want to place this data calls in a factory. After searching on so many websites i found this:

```
"use strict";
    angular.module("app")
        .factory('someFactoryName', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/foo/bar/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT' // this method issues a PUT request
                }
            });
        })
```

Now i can use this factory in my controller like this:

```
$scope.entry = new someFactoryName();
$scope.entry.$save(function (response) {
     //some code
});
```

Till here everything is fine.

**-- Now what i want to achieve --**

I have seen John Papa's [Angular1 Style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and i found [this](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#data-services) section, the code he demonstrated is very good i want to achieve the same thing i mean he called the ajax call and handled the response in the separate factory but here my case is little different. My only challenge is that he have used `$http` and i want to use `$resource` but for `$resource` i already have a factory then how can i write the response handling code in the same factory in which `$resource` is configured. I have 2 ideas in mind:

1. I can define one more factory and can inject this factory into new one,
2. Somehow write the code in this same factory

   I don't know which one is best and how to achieve it, if you have any idea please help. Thanks.

Comment: If not using $resource is an option, i strongly recommend to have a look on https://github.com/mgonto/restangular. It is much more flexible then $resource and is very simple to achieve what you need in **one** factory.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the first option. 
[Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is important.